# What are detailed differences between IPFS vs Storj vs Sia vs Filecoin vs Maidsafe? And which one is the best to use for dapps?

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, ipfs

I found lots of decentralized data storage out there but I am a little bit confused about these services. I am not able to figure out which service is best in which scenario? If anyone knows any examples related these then please give.
I have found two examples:

1. IPFS is used by [steemit](https://steemit.com) dapps(like [dtube](https://d.tube)).
2. Swarm is used by ethereum based projects with the help of [web3 API](http://www.ethdocs.org/en/latest/contracts-and-transactions/web3-base-layer-services.html?highlight=swarm).

Answer (score 0):

IPFS is a protocol for a distributed file system. Ethereum used IPFS for its core module. steemit and dtube are example of IPFS implementation. After open source, many people came with different application of IPFS.